# why can't i open an intent from the answer yes inside an alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

what i am trying to do is to open another activity from this activity when the answer is No from the alert dialog but it keep showing this activity with empty list ! i don't know why this is happening .. please can anyone help me?

```
public class CartList extends Activity {

    ListView list;

    static List<CartItems> detailsList = new ArrayList<CartItems>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_list);

        initializeComponents();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CartList.this);


            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("easy shopping");


            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you like to Continue shopping?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();


                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                         launchIntent();

                    }


                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();          
                alertDialog.show();

    }

    private void initializeComponents()
    {
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    }


    private void SetAdapterList() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CartItems details;
         //List<CartItems> detailsList = new ArrayList<CartItems>();
         List<CartItems> testList=new ArrayList<CartItems>();
         try{
         Intent newintent = getIntent();
         final String itemname = newintent.getStringExtra("itemname");
        final String itemprice = newintent.getStringExtra("itemprice");
        final String itemquantity = newintent.getStringExtra("itemquantity");
        final double totalprice = newintent.getDoubleExtra("totalprice", 0.0);
        String totprice=String.valueOf(totalprice);

        final int imagehandler=newintent.getIntExtra("image", 0);
        Log.e("image handler",imagehandler+"");
        details = new CartItems(itemname,itemprice,itemquantity,totprice,imagehandler);
        detailsList.add(details);

        Log.e("detailslsit",detailsList+"");
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }



  @Override
protected void onResume() {
      SetAdapterList();


    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,detailsList);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    super.onResume();
}  

  private void launchIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),PersonalInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you put the `launchIntent()` inside your negative comment which is `no` it should be inside the `positive button` which is yes

**Solution:**

Just switch it from positive to negative and vice verse....

======================================

when you are changing the intent dont use the baseContext just say `this`

**change this :**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),PersonalInfo.class);
```

**to:**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,PersonalInfo.class);
```

Comment: no sorry i want it to start from the no answer i will edit my question